# unity3D + kinect interection

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk

guys i am working on a project which uses unity engien and kinect as input source ..now according to my knowledge there is not much support between unity and kinect sdk ..i have heard about zigfu framework but it is not giving me all functionalities i need..so what are options for me? im thinking to take some functionalities from zigfu and some from a background application build in .net 4.0 and using kinect official sdk ? can i connect to kinect via two interfaces at the same time? i.e zigfu and kinect sdk ....my background app will connect to unity via pipes ..is that agood option?

Comment: Try [this](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Microsoft_Kinect_-_Microsoft_SDK). I've had the link bookmarked for awhile but I haven't yet tried their wrapper so I don't know what capabilities it offers.  Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I've already done something similar. I'd like to use Unity 3D engine and do some interactions to animate the model using Kinect (Kinect SDK). Some functionality in Kinect SDK are not available in Zigfu, such as Hand Gripping detection.

Because Kinect SDK is suitable for WPF application, here is my solution :

1. Build your Unity into Unity Standalone (PC, Mac, Linux).
2. Create WPF application with Kinect stuff inside.
3. Add WindowsFormsHost inside your XAML of WPF application.
4. Embed your Unity Standalone into WPF using WindowsFormsHost.
5. To do a communication between WPF and Unity, you can use Raknet. It will work as socket does.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, its usually not a good idea to use "two of" something, when they both do the same thing. I've never heard of zigfu before, but it seems relatively easy to learn. Since its available as a unity plug in, it may be best to use that over kinect. The reason being that Unity isn't to "friendly" with third party applications.

If your aiming for XNA, its possible to convert easily if the plug-in doesn't already do it for you.

I Highly recommend looking over the unity forums, and the ZDK documentation.
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/127924-Zigfu-dev-kit-for-Unity3D-Product-Launch

Comment: thanx for answer alex ...you are absolutly right..but i cant go with XNA ..it need more time to code whhich i don't have...is there any other wrapper available which provide most of the functionalities provided by kinect SDK?